I want to display a shimmer effect in scrollViewDidScroll
I have three state
 enum State {
        case loading
        case loaded
        case error
    }

The code applies a shimmer effect to the tableView when it loads. Here’s the code:
extension RecipientsRootVC: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        viewModel?.numberOfSection() ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return state == .loading ? 5 : (viewModel?.numberofRow(in: section)).safe
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if state == .loading {
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecipientShimmerCell", for: indexPath) as! RecipientShimmerCell
                    return cell
        } else {
            guard let model = viewModel?.list?[indexPath.row] else {
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
            let cell: RecipientCell = tableView.dequeCell(RecipientCell.self,
                                                          for: indexPath)
            cell.configure(data: RecipientCellVM(model: model))
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            
            cell.fullCellClicked = {
                self.viewModel?.getRecipientDetails(model.id.safe)
            }
            cell.onRightArrowClicked = {
                self.viewModel?.getRecipientDetails(model.id.safe)
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
}

The shimmer effect is visible when the tableView first loads, but it does not appear for newly loaded data when users scroll to trigger pagination.
extension RecipientsRootVC: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        
        if(scrollView != recentCollectionView) {
            let contentOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height
            let threshold: CGFloat = 10.0
            
            if maximumOffset - contentOffsetY <= threshold {
                guard !loadingData else{
                    return
                }
                length += 10
                viewModel?.loadMoreRecipients(length: length)
                print("Paging called \(length)")
                loadingData = true
            }
        }
    }
}

There are two additional functions that manage the dataLoadingStartedState and dataLoadingCompletedState states.
extension RecipientsRootVC: RecipientsViewModelDelegate {
    func dataLoadingStarted() {
        print("Data loading started.")
    }
    
    func dataLoadingCompleted(success: Bool) {
        if success {
            state = .loaded
            print("Data loading completed successfully.")
        } else {
            state = .error
            print("Data loading failed.")
        }
    }
}

How can I implement a shimmer effect that displays while new data loads as the user scrolls down?

Let's say in your view model you have:
class ViewModel {
    enum Row { case shimmer, recipient(Recipient) }
    var list = [Row]()
}

// In RecipientsViewModelDelegate
func dataLoadingStarted() {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    for _ in 0..<expectedRowsCountToLoad {
        viewModel.list.insert(.shimmer)
        tableView.insertRow(...)
    }
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func dataLoadingCompleted(success: Bool) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    for (idx, row) in viewModel.list.reversed().enumerated() {
        if case .shimmer = row {
            list.remove(at: idx)
            tableView.removeRow(...)
        }
    }
    if success {
        for recipient in newRecipients {
            viewModel.list.insert(.recipient(recipient))
            tableView.insertRow(...)
        }
    }
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

